# Publishing a FeatureService in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-service

I have a registered PostGIS DB in ArcGIS Server Enterprise > Site > DataStore.

How to create a FeatureService in ArcGIS Server from my PostGIS DB to create a FeatureLayer in JS app? 
How to obtain the URL that shows this example ?

```
const layer = new FeatureLayer({
  // URL to the service
  url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/"
});
```

Comment: You're missing a huge step -- you need to look up __publishing__. https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/publishing-feature-services.htm

Comment: Thanks @KHibma, I know how to create a FeatureLayer from an ArcGIS Portal item ID. I had already done with ArcGIS Pro 2.5.0 > Share > Share As WebMap ("Reference registered data: Exploratory").
My question is: how to create a FeatureLayer from a **service URL**. Where can I find this URL ?

Comment: Did you enable the feature capability when you published the service? This is nescessary to create a feature service. After that you can examine the rest endpoint of arcgis server to get the feature service url. Https://<host>/<web adapter>/rest/services

Comment: Thank you all ! After publishing a MapService I have seen where to find the URL to the service. Also I found the URL in my WebMap published.